# Conductivity formula for Metals

Tags: resistance, temperature, electricity, physics, conductivity

Is there any expression for the direct change in conductivity of metals with temperature ?

I am aware of change in resistivity with temperature.

Comment: Conductivity is the inverse of resistivity.

Comment: If with 'expression for the direct change' you mean an exact mathematical model, there are a few of various accuracy (starting with simple electron-cloud concepts to full-on quantum-mechanics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$\sigma = \frac1\rho $$

and, for a good approximation on typical temperatures where the metal is solid and and warmer than 180 K (==-90 °C):

$$\rho = \rho_0 + \alpha T$$

(with $\alpha$ being the temperature coefficient) it follows that

$$\sigma = \frac1{\rho_0 + \alpha T} $$